# How to enable SCM polling with the Jenkins Pipeline plugin

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

This is a question related to [How to make SCM polling work with the Jenkins Workflow plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123759/how-to-make-scm-polling-work-with-the-jenkins-workflow-plugin). That thread answers how to use SCM polling in a pipeline script **once** SCM polling is enabled but does not cover how to **enable** SCM polling.

For example, if you wanted to use the [mulit-branch pipeline plugin](https://jenkins-ci.org/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins/) to create jobs automatically using a Jenkinsfile there is not a way I know of to have the "Poll SCM" option enabled in the job.  This makes it difficult to provision on-demand environments such as creating a docker container that has the jobs setup from the beginning.  Because you would have to sign-in to Jenkins and go to the configuration and select the "Poll SCM" option once the container was started.  Cloudbees offers a [template plugin](https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205028534-How-do-I-configure-SCM-Polling-in-a-Pipeline-Template-?input_string=SCM%20Polling%20for%20Pipeline%20script) to help solve this problem.

However this is not available to Jenkins using the free version.  Is there any workaround or solution for users on the free version of Jenkins?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> if you wanted to use the multi-branch pipeline plugin to create jobs automatically using a Jenkinsfile there is not a way I know of to have the "Poll SCM" option enabled in the job

Nor is any needed. Multibranch projects have a configurable polling interval for the branch indexing as a whole, which also serves as a per-branch build trigger, and will also receive webhooks automatically.

Comment: You are right. The way my setup works is a top level multibranch job that polls a project using "Periodically if not otherwise run" in Bitbucket every 10 minutes.  A job is created for each branch with a Jenkinsfile in any repo under that project. It's also worth mentioning that the auto-created branch job will have the setting "Periodically if not otherwise run" option under Build Triggers defaulted to 1 day.  It doesn't appear to do anything and you cannot save changes to the job, so it cannot be modified.

Comment: The periodic trigger on the read-only multibranch project inside an organization folder ensures that branch indexing is run on that repository at least that interval if it has not been otherwise. The periodic trigger on the organization folder applies only to repository scanning, for example looking for new repositories to add. Currently the trigger at the multibranch project level is not configurable as an option at the organization folder level.

Comment: Do I need to set "Periodically if not otherwise run" on the root project for this to work? It seems that just causes my project built every 10min (or watever the interval is). It also ignores any settings for excludedRegions in GitSCM.

Comment: @JesseGlick, are you saying that the "Periodically if not otherwise run" is hard-coded at 1 day for the read-only project inside the org folder, so that can't be changed? Given that webhooks aren't a great option for Jenkins instances inside a VPN/intranet, how do they get built more often than daily?

Comment: What is the difference internally between interval polling and SCM polling - isn't the first more resource-intensive ? Will a 5sec interval have a negative impact on Jenkins performances?

Comment: This does not work for SVN using externals when one external changes, but not the top repository.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 23):

To answer the question how to enable SCM polling, you need to do the following.

Using the Pipeline Syntax generator and "properties: Set job properties" you can generate the following which will enable SCM polling.

```
properties([pipelineTriggers([pollSCM('H * * * *')])])
```

However as Jesse Glick points out for Multibranch pipelines you don't need to enable SCM polling.

Comment: This is the right answer, and using pollSCM('') enables job triggering only.

Comment: Does this poll for a change in the jenkinsfile? So will it run the job only of the jenkinsfile changes?

Answer (score 3):

I am thinking about the same problem.

If you are using a online Git service like `Github` or `Bitbucket`, I think you could use their `Webhooks` features to solve it. I have not been able to test the solution yet, but it **should** work.

In your `Multibranch Pipeline` configuration, enable the `Trigger builds remotely` option.

Then you need to enable your Github/Bitbucket Webhook on your repository, using the path (as described in the Jenkins configuration descrition): `JENKINS_URL/job/test/build?token=TOKEN_NAME`

Comment: There is also `Auto-register webhooks` option that should auto-generate the Webhook for you, but I have not been able to get this working

Comment: I can setup webhooks from GitHub and it does trigger builds, unfortutely I need to be able to update version number stored in the repo which causes infinite look and webhook trigger doesn't respect "excludedRegions" specified fro GitSCM. Any suggestion on how to exclude certain changes from triggering the build?

Comment: For Bitbucket - https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226568007-Triggering-a-build-using-hooks-in-Bitbucket-server

Answer (score 3):

In order to get my Bitbucket to connect to the web hook, I had to add the following to my declarative pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Initialize') {
            steps {
                //enable remote triggers
                script {
                    properties([pipelineTriggers([pollSCM('')])])
                }
                //define scm connection for polling
                git branch: BRANCH_NAME, credentialsId: 'my-credentials', url: 'ssh://git@stash.server.fqdn/stash/my-project.git'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows to rebuild a branch, without scanning the entire *multibranchiverse*. This is especially valuable, when using Bitbucket Project /Github Team-multibranch projects. There a scan can take a few minutes, once you have a few repos/branches.

By directly being able to hook into the branch, you can get a build result much faster, and without any side effects.

NB: In a declarative pipeline the properties call has to be wrapped by a script-block.